# What is the best way to manage terraform multi repo? Each repo has terraform scripts for each application infrastructure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We have a multi repo structure for our terraform scripts and there are lot of shared resources among these repo's. We want to restructure these repo's using modularization like calling one resource from one repo to another repo using module source . What is the best approach for cleaning the scripts and modularize?

Comment: This is too broad and primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to define a "best" approach as there will be tradeoffs that depend on your particular setup, particularly when it comes to cleaning and modularizing your terraform files.

You're best bet for getting a specific answer is to ask a more specific question. I'd suggest starting with the [HashiCorp Learn tutorial on Reuse Configuration with Modules](https://learn.hashicorp.com/collections/terraform/modules?utm_source=WEBSITE&utm_medium=WEB_IO&utm_offer=ARTICLE_PAGE&utm_content=DOCS)
 which includes a section on securely sharing your modules in a private module registry.

If you work through those sections and hit a particular problem, you'll almost certainly get a response here if you ask for help on solving that specific problem.